# Install Magento 2 in Amazon Linux (AWS)

Tags: magento-2.1, aws, centos

I installed magento 2 in amazon linux(centos) successfully. After doing styling and deploying, product images are not loaded. Add to cart is not working. it redirects to cart page without adding any item. There is knockout js issue

[image]

Error

ReferenceError: customer is not defined
  path.../en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js line 2624 > Function
  Line 1

I copied this installation and installed in my windows 10 machine, it works fine. There is no js issue.

========================Update 1====================================

I followed [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#mage-owner-about-group) document.

I suspect that I have permission issue in the server. 
my root folder permission

[image]

Inner folder permissions

[image]

var folder permission

[image]

pub folder permission

[image]

=======================Update 2==================================

I have executed command and attached screenshot herewith.

sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache var

suod chmod -R 777 var

[image]

Is there anyone who has this kind of experience will be helpful to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: permission issue?

Comment: Yes. It seems permission issue. Updated the question with screen shots. Please check.

Comment: Please change the user:group permission of var folder recursively. From the csreenshot given above, Both the user and group created are both apache but the parent folder is having the ownership of ec2user. Please give the ec2-user ownership for user in var folder and test this.

Go to the doc-root of the website and execute the following commands and please share the screenshot.

chown -R ec2-user:apache  var 

Above will change the user:group ownership

Also chmod -R 777 var

And test this.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar  Updated the question